# Calculating 2^n%k using only integers

Tags: java, integer, square

I need to write a code that gets 2 variables (n,k) and prints the answer to (2^n)%k.

I can use integers only, no methods, no arrays, no math. and so on.
so far i have this:

```
int n = myScanner.nextInt();  
    int k = myScanner.nextInt();   
    int num = 1;
    int modulo = 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {    
            num = num * 2;  
            modulo *= 2%k;

    }

    modulo = modulo%k;
    System.out.println(modulo);
```

the problem is the range of the int itself, doesn't go more than 2^31... but still i need to make it work somehow, any help would be really appreciated!

Comment: *"no math"*? The entire assignment *is* math. `(2^n)%k` *is* math.

Comment: i think by "no math", OP must mean "No java.lang.Math" !? :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are dealing with [Modular exponentiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_exponentiation). One possible solution is to avoid multiplication on large numbers, that will overflow the `int`, by taking advantage of below:

> Given two integers a and b, the following two equations are equivalent:
>
> c mod m = (a ⋅ b) mod m
>
> c mod m = [(a mod m) ⋅ (b mod m)] mod m

In Java a simple solution based on algorithm explained in this [section](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_exponentiation#Memory-efficient_method):

```
int mod(int base, int exponent, int modulus) {
  if (modulus == 1) return 0;
  int c = 1;
  for (int i = 0; i < exponent; i++) {
    c = (c * base) % modulus;
  }
  return c;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your problem is that it can't store more than 2^31 it's because you need to use a long datatype to store the value. A long can store a maximum value of 2^63 (signed).

Comment: If you're going to downvote a response is always appreciated! Thanks :)

Comment: i know that long would be more suited, but the task is to write a code that does this using only Int.